# Is there a way to filter listBlobFlatSegment on azure blob storage by the end of their names?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to get the blob name of the list of blobs on a container that is the most recent and that finish with something like this "_20167", all the files are type XML and have the following structure: " {UUID}_{DocumentType}_{Status}_{Source}_{CompanyNumber}.xml", for example: "1CE6A613-3D64-40E9-B17F-68C063ABC613_2C98EF3B-038B-4AA4-91E1-6FC32E012974_factura_vigente.xml".

I am using the prefix of *containerURL.listBlobFlatSegment* method but I could not find the way to change the functionality to use the prefix to search at the ending.
Here is my function code, I only pass the container name and de param to be searched, this is called "companyNumber":

```
async downloadListOfBlobs({ containerName, companyNumber }) {
    try {
      const containerURL = ContainerURL.fromServiceURL(
        this._serviceURL,
        containerName
      );
      let marker;
      marker = undefined;
      let blobsInContainer = [];
      const prefix = `${companyNumber}.xml`;
      do {
        const listBlobsResponse = await containerURL.listBlobFlatSegment(
          Aborter.none,
          marker,
          { include: null,
          maxresults: marker , 
          prefix }
        );

        marker = listBlobsResponse.nextMarker;
        for (const blob of listBlobsResponse.segment.blobItems) {
          console.log(`Blob: ${blob.name}`);
          blobsInContainer.push(`${blob.name}`);
        }
      } while (marker);
      return blobsInContainer[0] ? blobsInContainer[0] : '';
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

I was searched for another method to search dynamically on the full list of blobs but I didn't get enough information. 
So thanks a lot for your orientation!.

Comment: You can use underscore to split the filename and search company number in position 4 of the array. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Thanks a lot, taking in count your idea I could separate de full list of blobs of my interested blobs, however, I still can not filter directly for lisBlobFlatSegment function only the documents with the end equal to my company number, and this situation danger the performance function.  Here is the full new code:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the response, taking in count your idea I could separate de full list of blobs of my interested blobs, however, I still can not filter directly for lisBlobFlatSegment function only the documents with the end equal to my company number, and this situation danger the performance function. Here is the full new code:

````
    try {
      const containerURL = ContainerURL.fromServiceURL(
        this._serviceURL,
        containerName
      );
      let marker;
      marker = undefined;
      let blobsInContainer = [];
      let blobsInContainerNames = [];
      const prefix = `${companyNumber}.xml`;
      do {
          const listBlobsResponse = await containerURL.listBlobFlatSegment(
            Aborter.none,
            marker,
          );
          marker = listBlobsResponse.nextMarker;
          for (const blob of listBlobsResponse.segment.blobItems) {
            if ((prefix && blob.name.endsWith(prefix)) || !prefix) {
              blobsInContainer.push(blob);
            }
          }
        } while (marker);
        blobsInContainer.sort(function(a,b){
          return new Date(b.properties.lastModified) - new Date(a.properties.lastModified);
        })
        for (const blob of blobsInContainer) {
          if ((prefix && blob.name.endsWith(prefix)) || !prefix) {
            blobsInContainerNames.push(blob.name);
          }
        }
        console.log('blobSelected', blobsInContainerNames[0]);
        return blobsInContainerNames[0] ? blobsInContainerNames[0] : '';

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
      }
    }```
````